# Django admin multiple table display

Tags: django

We have following Database design

Payment table with user id from user table
Profile table one-to-one with User table
Registration table one to one with User table

In the admin system we want to provide the profile object with Payment details and  Registration Details. 
As there is no foreign key relation between Regsitration and profile table Can we achieve an inline of Registration details within Profile object in admin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear.... could you please explain the database design in a better way, so that we can understand better and give quick response...

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Django assumes that inline models have a direct relationship to their parent, and you can't do an inline "through" another table. If I'm wrong, someone please correct me.

I would write my own view in this case, as it's going to be easier, imo, than trying to tweak admin to get it to do what you need.

Comment: I agree with you. It is easier to write own view(s) than try to reload (override) django-admin.

Comment: But, of course, we have django-admin-tools. There you can change mostly anything.

Comment: Awesome - I didn't know about django-admin-tools. It's almost a full-time job keeping up with new packages! Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks for that info..I will tryout the admin-tools .Hope that helps .I find admin pretty basic.Would the admin tool work like a reporting tool as well

Comment: Admin is very extensible. You can make it do pretty much whatever you want.